# How can I describe this complex json model in swagger

Tags: json, rest, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I'm trying to use swagger to describe a rest api I added to some code.

This is one of my simple returns.

Saw a couple good examples but didn't have any luck trying to make sense how to apply it to my problem.

The different API calls will contain different content.

If I know what this one should look like I aught to be able to figure the others out.

Can anyone tell me what this description should look like?

```
{    
    "result" : {
      "content" : {
         "UNTAINTED_HOST" : "www.google.com",
         "DATA" : [
            "216.58.217.36"
         ],
         "IP_or_NAME" : "NAME",
         "RC" : "true",
         "FAULT_MSG" : "No Faults"
      },
      "detail" : "Sucessfully terminated your request",
      "short" : "Done"    } 
}
```

Or this even simpler one:

```
{
   "result" : {
      "short" : "Done",
      "detail" : "Sucessfully terminated your request",
      "content" : "Running"
   }
}
```

Think it would look like -

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "result": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "short", "detail", "content"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
                    "content": {
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    "detail": {
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    "short": {
                      "type": "string"
                    },
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Tried this in the swagger editor... seems I missed something.

```
definitions: 
  results: 
    type: object
    required: [ result ]
    properties: 
      result: 
        type: array
        items: 
          $ref: #/definitions/result

  result: 
    type: object
    properties: 
      short: 
        type: string
      detail: 
        type: string
      content: 
        type: string
```

This seemed to work:

```
  results: 
    type: object
    required: [ result ]
    properties: 
      result: 
        type: array
        items: 
          type: object
          required: [ short, detail, content ]
          properties: 
            short: 
              type: string
            detail: 
              type: string
            content: 
              type: string
```

Thanks

Comment: Compare http://editor.swagger.io/#!/ with yours.  There's a few top-level items it looks like you're missing.  If you drop your spec in the editor it'll quickly point them out: i.e. missing paths, info, swagger.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
definitions:
  result: 
    type: object
    properties: 
      short: 
        type: string
      detail: 
        type: string
      content: 
        type: string

  results: 
    type: object
    required: [result]
    properties: 
      result: 
        type: array
        items: 
          $ref: '#/definitions/result'
```

Notice the single quotes around the value of `$ref`.  I didn't see those in your original post.  However, you didn't mention the error you are seeing.  If this answer doesn't help, please update your question with more details.